# Send to Service Bus Queue with Windows?

Tags: azure, queue, servicebus

I know & can send messages to service bus queue using shared secret token, however now I want to send to the same queue using windows credential. How can I do that?

I have already added ADFSv2 to ACS .

Thanks,

Umang Parikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so, you need to first obtain a claim token(SAML) from ADFS.
Once you have the SAML token, you can use the token to access your Service Bus namespace.
Very nice article that explain in details with code example can be found here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj136813.aspx